# jquery .on() event argument does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Kindly see this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/e9uwA/1/

What's supposed to happen here is that the smaller box should fadeout via css transition, then ontransitionend, adjust the height of the bigger box. It works fine in Chrome, Opera but it doesn't work in Firefox.

I think it has something to do with the second argument `event` on the .on() method of jQuery. If that isn't allowed, are there any other alternatives?

Thank you!

Oh and disregard the comments written in the fiddle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your `event` handling a bit the wrong way round. Some browsers have a built-in object called `event` which happens to have a `stopPropagation()` method. Firefox does not. jQuery handles these differences elegantly, but you're not using it correctly.

Your event handlers are of the form:

```
.on('eventName', event, function(){...})
```

They should be

```
.on('eventName', function(evt){...})
```

Where `evt` is a jQuery wrapper around the event.

```
function start() {
    $('.childDiv').addClass('faded').on('transitionend', function(evt){
        evt.stopPropagation();
        //I suppose this ended the event listener for the childDiv
        $('.childDiv').off('transitionend');

        $('.parentDiv')
            .addClass('no-height')
            .on('transitionend',function(evt) {
                //why is 'opacity' being read? any way to fix this?
                alert(evt.propertyName);
            });
    });    
}
```

(However, note that the [`jQuery.Event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) does not have a property `propertyName` so that final `alert` will show `undefined`)

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/qCKcg/

Comment: It doesn't seem to read evt.propertyName anymore on Chrome. :(

Comment: @AJNaidas - Just had another look, and the thing you want is `evt.originalEvent.propertyName` - works in Chrome & FF.